# How to convert SQL query to OData query?

Tags: mysql, odata

I am using OData services. Everything is ready. I wanted to use one query which is in SQL and I have to use it as OData.

Below is my SQL query.

```
SELECT TOP 1 id from DeliverySiteFuses where Name>125
```

Below is my incomplete OData query

```
var delSiteFuseId = await dataClient.For<DeliverySiteFuse>()
                                              .Filter(x => x.Name gt 125)
                                              .FindEntryAsync();
```

Comment: What library provides this `dataClient` object?

Comment: IDataServicesClient

Comment: MySql not support odata service out of box. You need to converter between odata services to MySQL. Which programming language do you use?

Comment: Just curious to know, is there any plugin or something that does mapping of SQL query to OData one.